# how to append values to an global array extracted values from different parsing methods?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
import requests
import win32api
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from array import *
import itertools
import numpy


class firstSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "vdfgedu"
  allowed_domains = ["de.vdfg.edu"]
  start_urls = ["https://de.vdfg.edu/nephrology/node/1608"]
  globalarray = []
  def parse(self, response):
  #find all the hrefs first
      depts_with_info = []
      for dept_info in response.css('div.pane-content'):
               depts = {}
               links = dept_info.css('table.views-table tbody tr.viewsrow-first td a::attr(href)').extract()
               for link in links:
                       yield scrapy.Request("https://de.vdfg.edu"+link, callback = self.title_info)
                       yield scrapy.Request("https://de.vdfg.edu"+link+"#group-tabs-node-course-default3", callback = self.venue_info)
               def title_info(self, response):
                     titleinfo = {}
                     titleinfo['title'] = response.css('div.field-item h1::text').extract()
                     titleinfo['cmepoints'] = response.css('div.item-list ul.course-credit-list li span::text').extract()[0].strip()
                    self.globalarray.append(titleinfo)
              def venue_info(self, response):
                   venueinfo = {}
                   venueinfo['venue'] = response.css('div.adr span::text').extract()
                   self.globalarray.append(venueinfo)
```

i want to append values to an global array and to get into excel sheet wtih respective hrefs from above two different methods..how to declare global array?
can we append vaules from more than one parsing method?

Answer (score 0):

You can create data class member which can be used as global value across all the methods in class.

```
class firstSpider(BaseSpider):
    def __intit__(self):
        self.globalarray = []
```

Comment: then i'm getting no errors but except this : ScrapyDeprecationWarning: mayoclinic.spiders.mayos.firstSpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spiders.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class firstSpider(BaseSpider):